# right shift count >= width of type or left shift count >= width of type

Tags: c

I am new to bits, I am trying to get 64 bit value send using UDP.

```
int plugin(unsigned char *Buffer) {
     static const uint8_t max_byte = 0xFF;
     uint8_t id[8];
     id[0] = (uint8_t)((Buffer[0]) & max_byte);
     id[1] = (uint8_t)((Buffer[1] >> 8)  & max_byte);
     id[2] = (uint8_t)((Buffer[2] >> 16) & max_byte);
     id[3] = (uint8_t)((Buffer[3] >> 24) & max_byte);
     id[4] = (uint8_t)((Buffer[4] >> 32) & max_byte);
     id[5] = (uint8_t)((Buffer[5] >> 40) & max_byte);
     id[6] = (uint8_t)((Buffer[6] >> 48) & max_byte);
     id[7] = (uint8_t)((Buffer[7] >> 56) & max_byte);

}
```

I am getting error right shift count >= width of type. I tried other way aswell

```
int plugin(unsigned char *Buffer) {
     uint64_t id = (Buffer[0] | Buffer[1] << 8 | Buffer[2] << 16 | Buffer[3] << 24 | Buffer[4] < 32 | Buffer[5] << 40 | Buffer[6] << 48 | Buffer[7] << 56);
     printf("ID %" PRIu64 "\n", id);
}
```

Its getting error left shift count >= width of type
I checked the system it is x86_64. Could someone please tell me the reason why its happening? Please suggest me a way forward.

Comment: You have to cast your 8 bit values to 64 bit values before to shift them. Think of your 8 bit values as boxes with a width of 8cm. What happens to the content of a 8cm wide box when you shift it by 56 cm ?

Comment: Buffer points to an 8-bit type yet you are shifting more than 8-bits

Comment: Even if you do cast to a 64 bit type the first example doesn't make sense as you're not or-ing the results.

Comment: @Toby: Actually he shifts `int`, not `char`. But that only _shifts_ the problem.

Comment: @2501 True dat, I think Abu has misunderstood what he needs to do here . The first example seems to be converting an array of char data to an array of shifted uint8_t data which seems a bit pointless... the latter example seems better in this regard

Comment: Even if you cast, you will get `0` only. What is the reason to `& max_byte`?

Comment: @Olaf I think Abu intends the `& maxbyte` for truncating the upper bits above the 8th bit... but this is not needed.

Comment: @Toby: **After** shifting 8 bits into positions above bit 7?? That is not only useless, but plain wrong. OP should re-consider his concept of bit-ops.

Comment: @TimF "What happens to the content of a 8cm wide box when you shift it by 56 cm" - What happens if you shift by 7cm, which is allowed? Not a good analogy. FYI: The shifts don't operate on 8 bits (not possible in C), but whatever an `int` is on the architecture.

Comment: When you try to move the content 56cm inside the 8cm wide box, some lunatic from the C standard committee suddenly leaps in, and without asking snatches the box out of your hands, then puts the contents into another box, 32cm wide but otherwise entirely unsuitable for the given contents. (maybe the contents were warm food and he put it in a mini-fridge with negative temperature). You then try to move the contents 56cm inside that 32cm wide box, which doesn't work. The solution is to provide a large enough box from the start and also prevent that lunatic from interfering with your business.

Comment: Boxes are really complicated nowadays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because of default integer promotion, basically.

When you do this:

```
uint64_t id = Buffer[7] << 56;
```

That `Buffer[7]` is an `unsigned char`, but it gets promoted to `int` in the arithmetic expression, and your `int` is not 64 bits. The type of the left hand side does not automatically "infect" the right hand side, that's just not how C works.

You need to cast:

```
const uint64_t id = ((uint64_t) Buffer[7]) << 56;
```

and so on.

Comment: Sligthly worse: It gets promoted to `int`, not `unsigned int`. And there are more issues.